# How to determine QString reserve size for a PL/SQL bind value

Tags: c++, string, oracle, qt, plsql

I am attempting to load a CLOB from a query to Oracle PL/SQL into a String bound value.

The code that does this is:

```
QString testStr ="*****";
// testStr.truncate(0);
testStr.reserve( 1000000 );
qDebug() << testStr.capacity();
query.bindValue(":result_clob", testStr, QSql::Out);
bool query_executed_ok = query.exec();
qDebug() << "did it execute?" << query_executed_ok;
if (query_executed_ok) {
    testStr = query.boundValue(":result_clob").toString();
    qDebug() << testStr;
} else {
    qDebug() << "string is empty";
}
```

Initially I was having a problem with the string buffer being to small, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59940028/qt-pl-sql-assignment-operator-character-string-buffer-too-small/59954820#59954820)

But later discovered if I increased the string buffer on QString to some (Arbitrary?) value it seems to work. I assume this buffer size is in bytes.

How do I determine what size to make this buffer so that my return values do not run out of memory with the error `"numeric or value error: character string buffer too small"`

Comment: can you show an example of the select query you are using?  In practical terms, how big can this clob data get?

Comment: That error is coming from Oracle not from the C++ code. It is extremely unlikely that the reserved capacity of a QString object has anything todo with it.

Comment: It's a procedure call - at the end of it I assign the CLOB string to a binded return value ```:result_clob := l_clob;```

As for the length, it could vary depending on how much data the user could request. I can set an upper limit though in the procedure to help reduce the chance of the buffer running out. 

As for the error coming from Oracle. I thought so too. In my previous post (link above) I mentioned the error ```ORA-06502```, but again when I change in my C++ code, not the PL/SQL, the string reserve size it just starts working and prints the string.